# GitHub Actions Runner Image - boost for macOS arm64

Tags: macos, github-actions

How do I deploy boost for arm64 to a GitHub Actions Runner Image under macOS?

I am using Github Actions to build my project, which depends on boost.

As far as I can tell, when I set the YAML label to `macos-11`, the runner image itself is intel.

For my x86_64 build, I simply say

```
brew install boost
```

And the job can then go on to compile and link my own code successfully.

If I understand correctly, it is not possible to use brew to install boost arm64 binaries to a macOS intel machine.

Maybe I could build boost from source using something like

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 install
```

What flags would I pass to tell it to cross compile the arm64 binaries?

**Edit**:  I found the solution and posted the answer below, stack overflow tells me that I do not have enough karma to mark my own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of this page...

[B2 4.7.1 MacOS Armv8 package bundles x86_64 binary](https://github.com/b0fgroup/b2/issues/105)

...it says:

```
./b2 architecture=arm address-model=64 -s NO_LZMA=1 -s NO_ZSTD=1 abi=aapcs
```

That worked for me.  The entire step that I have on github actions is:

```
- name: Boost
  run: |
    curl -O -L https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.80.0/source/boost_1_80_0.tar.gz
    tar xfz boost_1_80_0.tar.gz
    cd boost_1_80_0
    ./bootstrap.sh
    ./b2 architecture=arm address-model=64 -s NO_LZMA=1 -s NO_ZSTD=1 abi=aapcs install
    lipo /usr/local/lib/libboost_*.dylib -info
```